# Is there a mereological system treating both parts and wholes?

Tags: logic, foundations

In the papers I read, the parthood relation is treated as a relation between two parts of one whole. I did not read any paper about the relation between a part of a whole and the whole. How this relation is treated in mathematical terms? I am not interested specifically in parthood relation. Is there an mereological system treating in any terms, by using relations or operations, the things which are referenced as ``whole'' within a domain of discourse where there are also parts?

Comment: Not clear... See [Mereology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mereology/): "the theory of parthood relations: of the relations of part to whole and the relations of part to part within a whole."

Comment: Regarding the "interpretation" of the standard Mereological relation $Pxy$, the *domain* will be the "whole" and the variables $x,y$ will range over *parts* of that whole. So the issue is: are you asking about a theory where there are more than one "whole"?

Comment: Maybe you can see David Lewis, [Parts of Classes (Blackwell, 1991)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/38355446_Book_review_David_Lewis_Parts_of_classes)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA. Yes, I am asking about a theory where there are more than one "whole". I read David Lewis' book. It is about mereology of one "whole".

Comment: Is the distinction relevant? You can simply consider the two "wholes" $D_1$ and $D_2$ as parts of a new "whole" $D = D_1 \cup D_2$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA You wrote "the *domain* will be the whole". This is a metalinguistic statement. A system cannot discuss about its domain of discourse like you or I do. I am asking whether or not there exist a mereological system which discusses about wholes and their parts. But also your statement that the things withing the universe are ``parts" of the domain sounds unclear - in what sense they are parts of the domain? They are elements of the domain.